# Database Design: How should I store 'word difficulty' in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I made a vocabulary app for Android that has a list of ~5000 words stored in a local database (SQLite), and I want to find out which words are more difficult than others.

To find out, I'm thinking of adding a very simple feature that puts two random words on the screen, asking the user to choose the more difficult one. Then another pair of random words will show, and this process can be repeated for as long as the user wants. The more users who participate in this 'more difficult word', the app would in theory be able to distinguish difficult words from easy words.

Since the difficulty would be based on input from all users, I know I need to keep track of it online so that every app could then fetch them from the database on my website (which is MySQL). I'm not sure what would be the most efficient way to keep track of the difficulty, but I came up with two possible solutions:

1) Add a `difficulty` column that holds integer values to the words table. Then for every pair of words that a user looks at and ranks, the word that he/she chooses more difficult would have have its difficulty increased by one, and the word not chosen would have its difficulty decreased by one. I could simply `order by` that integer value to get the most difficult ones.

2) Create a `difficulty` table with two columns, `more` and `less`, that hold words (or `ID's` of the words to save space) based on the results of each selection a user makes. I'm still unsure how I would get the most difficult words - some combination of `group by` and `order by`?

The benefit of my second solution is that I can know how many times each word has been seen (# of rows from the `more` column that contain the word + # rows from the `less` column that contain the word). That helps with statistics, like if I wanted to find out which word has the highest ratio of `more` / `less`. But it would also take up much more space than my first suggested solution would, and don't know how it could scale.

Which do you think is the better solution, or what other ones should I consider?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about application design, not database design

Comment: @JoelBrown are you saying `database-design` was a bad tag choice, or that this question is better for StackOverflow instead of this site? I'm mainly interested in what structure I should use to store this information - it might be for an application but I just wanted to give context.

Comment: it's "its", not "it's"

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I just fixed that mistake, even though it's not a big deal because of its low significance compared to the actual question

Comment: Eh? But the question's about *word difficulty* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try sphinx for this? Guess a full text search engine like sphinx would solve with great performance.

Comment: I just looked at it now as I had never heard of Sphinx before, but I don't understand how it could help